# unit testing file upload in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am using the nf-file-upload module to upload a file to my backend. The code for the file upload is as follows:

```
    $scope.upload = function (file) {
            console.log(file)

            Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/fileupload',
                data: {file: file[0]},
            }).then(function (resp) {
                console.log('Success ' + resp.config.data.file.name + ' uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
}
```

The file uploading works great. however, when I create my unit test:

```
  it('should send file to backend for processing', function(){
    var mockFile = {file:[{"name":"file.bin", "size":1018, "type":"application/binary"}]};
    httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/fileupload').respond(200, {"filePath":"http://localhost:3000/uploads/file.txt"});
    scope.upload(mockFile);
    httpBackend.flush();
  });
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'resp.config.data.file.name')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `then` method using the `resp` argument. In the normal conditions, you'll receive a object that have the structure:
    {
      config:{
       data: {
         file:{
           name: 'a name'}
         }
       }
     }

but in your test you don't respond with the same structure.

**EDIT:**
Ok. I got this. the way that ng-file-uploader returns the data it's not mockable. You don't get the name of the file in the resp.data.config.file.name, Instead, saves the filename in a variable before upload the file. 
Like this:

```
   $scope.upload = function (file) {

      var fileName = file.name;

      Upload.upload({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/fileupload',
        data: {file: file[0]},
      })
      .then(function (resp) {

        console.log('Success ' + fileName + ' uploaded. Response: ' + resp.data);
    });

  };
```

Check this codepen codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/MyrvQK Good luck!

Comment: adding a mock object like this as per the example below still results in a syntax error.

Comment: because your console.log also use `resp.data`,  add `data` in your object.
{config: {data: {file:{name: 'a name'}}}, data: {}}

Comment: httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/fileupload')
    .respond(200, { "config":
     { "data" :
         "file":
            {"name": "http://localhost:3000/uploads/file.txt" }
         }
     }, "data": {});

adding that still results in many 'unrecoverable syntax errors'

Comment: Ok. I got this. the way that ng-file-uploader returns the data it's not mockeable. You don't get name of the resp.data.config.file.name, Instead, saves the filename in a variable before upload the file. Check this codepen

http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/MyrvQK

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a digest cycle.

```
  it('should send file to backend for processing', function(){
    var mockFile = {file:[{"name":"file.bin", "size":1018, "type":"application/binary"}]};
    httpBackend.when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/fileupload').respond(200, {"filePath":"http://localhost:3000/uploads/file.txt"});
    scope.upload(mockFile);
    httpBackend.flush();
    scope.$digest();
  });
```

This will resolve the promise and trigger the return data.